# Installing ubuntu partitions problem

Tags: 12.10

I'm an Ubuntu newbie and I'm using it for the first time. During the installation I chose install Ubuntu over Windows, thinking that this will keep the partitions and install Ubuntu on the partition where the Windows was installed (C:) and keep the other one (D:) with all the files on it. After I installed I couldn't find the D:\ partition. Was It formatted as well, and if yes is there some way to retrieve it? Please help I'm desperate, I had some really important files on that partition!

Comment: You can run GParted Partition Editor to view all your current disk drives/partitions. Linux/Ubuntu does not have these letters, but sda1, sda2, etc.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZQu8aADv

Comment: It seems you have Ubuntu installed on sda1 and there's only sda5 left out. And if you cannot see your files there, you should do nothing else with this disk before recovering all the data overwritten during installation process.

Comment: Please specify how do I recover the data. I will be very thankfull :)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not experienced in this area, but it should be possible if you make sure that you don't do anything at all especially that involves writing data to disk (overwriting previous data) before such a data/partition recovery. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie also, so take this answer with a grain of salt.  Check your directory and see if you have a /Home directory.  This might be where you important files will be found.

Good luck.

Comment: This would not be the answer. The data is on a separate partition, and is not migrated/imported into Ubuntu in any way.s